# Replacing a complex, multi-conditional for loop in R with pivot_wider()

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

I have a "long" data frame in R, and I want to create a new "wider" data frame from it. I looked into using pivot_wider from dplyr, but I'm having trouble figuring it out since what I want to do is more complicated than the examples I can find. I have successfully used a for loop, but I want to see if there is a faster way to do this (pivot_wider or otherwise).

Here's a simplified example of the original data frame:

```
df
   USER_ID EVENT_ISCHECKED EVENT_VALUE EVENT_ID
1        4               0                 CB_1
2        4               1                 CB_2
3        4               1                 CB_3
4        4                                  V_1
5        4                          33      V_2
6        4                                  V_3
7        5               1                     
8        5               0                 CB_2
9        5               1                 CB_3
10       5                                  V_1
11       5                                  V_2
12       5                          47      V_3
```

The second data frame should have just one row for each USER_ID and separate columns for each EVENT_ID that are populated with indicator values (0 or 1). The tricky part is that the values they get come from different columns/conditionals. The CB (checkbox) columns get a 1 if EVENT_ISCHECKED==1, while the V (value) columns get a 1 if EVENT_VALUE has a number/isn't empty. The result from this simplified example should look like this:

```
outDF
  USER_ID CB_1 CB_2 CB_3 V_1 V_2 V_3
1       4    0    1    1   0   1   0
7       5    0    0    1   0   0   1
```

Here's my code with the for loop going through each row of the original data frame:

```
# Setting up the example data frame
df <- data.frame("USER_ID" = c(rep(4,6), rep(5,6)),
                 "EVENT_ISCHECKED" = c(0,1,1,"","","",1,0,1,"","",""),
                 "EVENT_VALUE" = c("","","","",33,"","","","","","",47),
                 "EVENT_ID" = c("CB_1","CB_2","CB_3","V_1","V_2","V_3","","CB_2","CB_3","V_1","V_2","V_3"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Vectors of possible checkbox and value codes
CB <- c("CB_1", "CB_2", "CB_3")
V <- c("V_1", "V_2", "V_3")

# Creating the ouput data frame with one row per user and
# separate columns for each Event ID with default value of 0
outDF <- unique(df[, 'USER_ID',drop = FALSE])
outDF[,CB] <- 0
outDF[,V] <- 0

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  # Going through each row and setting
  # the current User ID, Event ID, etc.
  U.ID <- df[[i, "USER_ID"]]
  E.ID <- df[[i, "EVENT_ID"]]
  E.CH <- df[[i, "EVENT_ISCHECKED"]]
  E.V <- df[[i, "EVENT_VALUE"]]
  
  # Getting the index of the row in the outDF
  # that matches the current User ID
  outputRow <- which(outDF$USER_ID == U.ID)
  
  # If the Event ID is one of the Check Box IDs and the
  # Event is checked, then that user gets a 1
  # in that CB column
  if(E.ID %in% CB & E.CH==1){
    outDF[outputRow, E.ID] <- 1
  }
  
  # If the Event ID is one of the Value IDs and the
  # value is not empty, then that user gets a 1
  # in that V column
  if(E.ID %in% V & E.V!=""){
    outDF[outputRow, E.ID] <- 1
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Starja's answer now works for the missing EVENT_ID case!

Comment: Just to be sure: Your intended behaviour is that missing values (here for `CB_1` for `USER_ID` 5) is 0 or `NA`? I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first make a column with the expected values and then use `pivot_wider` to generate the wide table:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame("USER_ID" = c(rep(4,6), rep(5,6)),
                 "EVENT_ISCHECKED" = c(0,1,1,"","","",1,0,1,"","",""),
                 "EVENT_VALUE" = c("","","","",33,"","","","","","",47),
                 "EVENT_ID" = c("CB_1","CB_2","CB_3","V_1","V_2","V_3","","CB_2","CB_3","V_1","V_2","V_3"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_wide <- df %>% 
  filter(EVENT_ID != "") %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when(str_detect(EVENT_ID, "^CB") ~ as.numeric(EVENT_ISCHECKED),
                           EVENT_VALUE == "" ~ 0,
                           TRUE ~ 1)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = USER_ID,
              names_from = EVENT_ID,
              values_from = value,
              values_fill = list(value = 0))

df_wide
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  USER_ID  CB_1  CB_2  CB_3   V_1   V_2   V_3
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       4     0     1     1     0     1     0
2       5     0     0     1     0     0     1
```

---

### Edit

I've included @IceCreamToucan's suggestion with `id_cols` into `pivot_wider` and @Martin Gal's suggestion to use `case_when` instead of `if_else`.

Now I also filter out rows with a missing `EVENT_ID` and replace these missing values with 0.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan thanks for the great suggestion, I've included it into my answer

Comment: Check out `case_when`. In my opinion it's better to read/understand as those nested `if_else`-statements.

Comment: Thanks, this looks close to what I need! The only possible problem is that some of the EVENT_IDs are missing but still have something in the EVENT_ISCHECKED or EVENT_VALUE columns. I set up row 7 in the example data frame to represent that. I'm going to add an edit to show how your code works in that case.

Comment: @MartinGal also thank you for the suggestion, your right, I've included it into my answer

Comment: @nzy2237 You could replace the `is.na(EVENT_VALUE)` with `EVENT_VALUE == ""` if you don't have `NA`s.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `coalecse` with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   transmute(USER_ID, EVENT_ID, 
             value = coalesce(EVENT_ISCHECKED, !is.na(EVENT_VALUE))) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = EVENT_ID, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 2 x 7
#  USER_ID  CB_1  CB_2  CB_3   V_1   V_2   V_3
#    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1       4     0     1     1     0     1     0
#2       5     1     0     1     0     0     1
```

---

If we want to get `NA` where both columns are `NA`, then do

```
df %>% 
   transmute(USER_ID, EVENT_ID, 
             value = replace(coalesce(EVENT_ISCHECKED, 
     !is.na(EVENT_VALUE)), is.na(EVENT_ISCHECKED) & is.na(EVENT_VALUE), NA %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = EVENT_ID, values_from = value)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(USER_ID = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), EVENT_ISCHECKED = c(0, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 1, 
NA, NA, NA), EVENT_VALUE = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 33, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 47), EVENT_ID = c("CB_1", "CB_2", "CB_3", "V_1", 
"V_2", "V_3", "CB_1", "CB_2", "CB_3", "V_1", "V_2", "V_3")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Thanks! This way works the same way as starja's in the missing EVENT_ID case, which is well-enough with just a bit of extra cleaning at the end.

Comment: @nzy2237 i see your expected output same as the solution